# LINQ - selecting elements with a specific day

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a class which has one of the properties as DateTime.

```
public class ClassWithDate
{
   public int somevalue {get;set;}
   public DateTime somedate {get;set;}
}
```

I have another List of string which holds values of day (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

```
List<string> someDays;
```

I have an IEnumerable list of the ClassWithDate

```
IEnumerable<ClassWithDate> classWithDates;
```

I wish to select those elements from classWithDates where the date property is NOT a day from the someDays list of string

Something like this:

```
classWithDates.someDate.DayOfWeek != someDays
```

I know the syntax is wrong, but just wanted to provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this.

```
var results = classWithDates.Where(wd=>!someDays.Contains(wd.somedate.DayOfWeek.ToString()));
```

or

```
var results = classWithDates.Where(wd=>!someDays.Any(s=> sq.Equals(wd.somedate.DayOfWeek.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Working [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g3xT92)

Comment: I already tried something on this line and get the following error: IEnumerable<List<string>> does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Comment: Do you have Collection of `List<string>` ?

Comment: flatten them if you have `IEnumerable<List<string>>`,   Add this line before query `someDays = someDays.SelectMany(s=>s);`

Comment: This did the trick! I was using someDays.Select for some other manipulation instead of SelectMany. I guess their return types are different which caused the error

Answer (score 1):

Let `List<string> days = new List<string>() { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday" };`   be the defined list of week days; and `classWithDates` be your collection; then the following query will help you to do the task:

```
var selectedDates = classWithDates.Where(x => !days.Contains(x.somedate.DayOfWeek.ToString()));
```

An example here :

```
 DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
 List<ClassWithDate> classWithDates = new List<ClassWithDate>();
 classWithDates.Add(new ClassWithDate() { somedate = d.AddDays(1), somevalue = 12 });
 classWithDates.Add(new ClassWithDate() { somedate = d.AddDays(2), somevalue = 12 });
 classWithDates.Add(new ClassWithDate() { somedate = d.AddDays(3), somevalue = 12 });
 classWithDates.Add(new ClassWithDate() { somedate = d.AddDays(4), somevalue = 12 });
 classWithDates.Add(new ClassWithDate() { somedate = d.AddDays(5), somevalue = 12 });
 classWithDates.Add(new ClassWithDate() { somedate = d.AddDays(6), somevalue = 12 });
 List<string> days = new List<string>() { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Friday" };
 var selectedDates = classWithDates.Where(x => !days.Contains(x.somedate.DayOfWeek.ToString()));
```

Comment: I already tried something on this line and get the following error: IEnumerable<List<string>> does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Comment: define ` days`  as ` List<string>()`

Comment: Thank you; the trick was to flatten the list as suggested by Hari Prasad

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 List<ClassWithDate> _sampleList=new List<ClassWithDate>(); 
_sampleList.Add(new ClassWithDate(){somevalue=10,somedate=new DateTime(1980, 5, 5)});
_sampleList.Add(new ClassWithDate(){somevalue=10,somedate=new DateTime(1982, 10, 20)});
_sampleList.Add(new ClassWithDate(){somevalue=10,somedate=new DateTime(1984, 1, 4)});
_sampleList.Add(new ClassWithDate(){somevalue=10,somedate=new DateTime(1979, 6, 19)});



List<string> daysList = new List<string>() { "Monday", "Tuesday" };
IEnumerable<ClassWithDate> selectedDates = _sampleList.Where(x => !daysList.Contains(x.somedate.ToString("dddd")));

foreach(ClassWithDate cl in selectedDates)
{
  Console.WriteLine(cl.somedate.ToString("dddd"));      
}
```

Comment: I already tried something on this line and get the following error: IEnumerable<List<string>> does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Comment: Have you added System.Linq to your namespace

Comment: Thank you; the trick was to flatten the list as suggested by Hari Prasad

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
  // Let be comparison case insensitive
  HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet(someDays, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  // providing that classWithDates doesn´t contain null items
  var result = classWithDates
    .Where(item => !hs.Contains(item.somedate.DayOfWeek.ToString()));
```